# AC adapter burnt due to high voltage spike but is my computer damaged because of this?

Tags: laptop, power, adapter

There was a high voltage spike in our area.

My laptop stopped working and the little bulb in the refrigerator stopped working as well as an air coniditioner.

When I touched the laptop I felt a current from the metal lining VAIO laptops have.

I asked a repairman to check the adapter out. He said the transformer was burnt and said that buying a new one is an option. I’ll buy a new one but I’m worried that my laptop is damaged too.

So are there any chances that my laptop got damaged too because of the high voltage?

Comment: If the laptop was not connected to a surge suppressor, then it is possible the laptop was damaged. You may get lucky and it was just the power adapter... Is the laptop able to boot off the battery? If so, does it work?

Comment: Power Cord - Surge Protector (APC) - AC Adapter - Laptop
The connections were made in that paticular order.
And the surge protector i used was this same exact model.
http://images.techtree.com/ttimages/story/80198_apc1.jpg

Comment: "When i touched the laptop i felt a current from the metal lining VAIO laptops have" - sounds like you have some electrical issues in your house rather than an issue with your laptop charger, or your charger isn't being grounded properly...

Answer (score -1):

Normally only the power supply will suffer damage from power surge.

The output side (to the computer) of the power supply is protected and limited to 18 Volts DC.

Here is typical process:

- First the transformer would burn out,
- Next the AC/DC converter would burn out.

Once the DC converter has died, there is no path for high voltage to get to your computer.

I would agree with the repair man and replace the transformer or get new power supply.

As for surge protector, it is to late for this event but you should get one for the future use.

Possible scenario where computer gets damaged:

If a lightning strikes it could/will damage your computer because the Voltage is so high it can JUMP over the components in your power supply all the way to you computer.

**EDIT:** Since you just now disclosed you did use a surge protector, it is likely that it was not doing the job.

Comment: Power Cord - Surge Protector (APC) - AC Adapter - Laptop The connections were made in that paticular order. And the surge protector i used was this same exact model. images.techtree.com/ttimages/story/80198_apc1.jpg

Comment: i already had the surge protector connected

Comment: Than it is a piece of crap, and did not do its job.

Comment: This one ! https://www.apc.com/tools/surge_selector/index.cfm